# RequireJS / Durandal fields always null

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

**PROBLEM**

**Durandal** or perhaps **RequireJS** seems to be making my properties null. My main view model has 3 sub models (**PostModel**, **CategoryModel**, **TagModel**) and all of these end up being empty objects.

**CODE**

**Main File: blog.js**

```
var viewModel;

define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'datajs', 'OData', 'Q', 'breeze', 'blog-posts', 'blog-categories', 'blog-tags'],
    function ($, ko, datajs, odata, Q, breeze, posts, categories, tags) {
        'use strict'

        var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.postModel = false;
            self.categoryModel = false;
            self.tagModel = false;

            self.activate = function () {
                self.postModel = new posts();
                self.categoryModel = new categories();
                self.tagModel = new tags();
            };
            self.attached = function () {
                breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "OData" });
                self.postModel.init();
                self.categoryModel.init();
                self.tagModel.init();
            };
            self.showCategories = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.showPosts = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.showTags = function () {
                //.....
            };
        };

        viewModel = new ViewModel();
        return viewModel;
    });
```

**post.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'jqueryval', 'knockout', 'kendo', 'kendo-knockout', 'notify'],
    function ($, jqueryval, ko, kendo, ko_kendo, notify) {
        'use strict'

        var PostModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.id = ko.observable(0);
            self.categoryId = ko.observable(0);
            self.headline = ko.observable(null);
            self.slug = ko.observable(null);
            self.teaserImageUrl = ko.observable(null);
            self.shortDescription = ko.observable(null);
            self.fullDescription = ko.observable(null);
            self.useExternalLink = ko.observable(false);
            self.externalLink = ko.observable(null);
            self.metaKeywords = ko.observable(null);
            self.metaDescription = ko.observable(null);

            self.availableTags = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.chosenTags = ko.observableArray([]);

            self.init = function () {
                //..... this code runs fine (initializes a Kendo Grid)
            };
            self.create = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.edit = function (id) {
                //.....
            };
            self.remove = function (id) {
                //.....
            };
            self.save = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.cancel = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.validator = $("#post-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    // JQuery Validation Rules
                }
            });
        };
        return PostModel
```

**tag.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'jqueryval', 'knockout', 'kendo', 'kendo-knockout', 'notify'],
    function ($, jqueryval, ko, kendo, ko_kendo, notify) {
        'use strict'

        var TagModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.id = ko.observable(0);
            self.name = ko.observable(null);
            self.urlSlug = ko.observable(null);

            self.init = function () {
                //..... this code runs fine (initializes a Kendo Grid)
            };
            self.create = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.edit = function (id) {
                //.....
            };
            self.remove = function (id) {
                //.....
            };
            self.save = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.cancel = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.validator = $("#tag-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    // JQuery Validation Rules
                }
            });
        };
        return TagModel;
    });
```

**category.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'jqueryval', 'knockout', 'kendo', 'kendo-knockout', 'notify'],
    function ($, jqueryval, ko, kendo, ko_kendo, notify) {
        'use strict'

        var CategoryModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.id = ko.observable(0);
            self.name = ko.observable(null);
            self.urlSlug = ko.observable(null);

            self.init = function () {
                //..... this code runs fine (initializes a Kendo Grid)
            };
            self.create = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.edit = function (id) {
                //.....
            };
            self.remove = function (id) {
                //.....
            };
            self.save = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.cancel = function () {
                //.....
            };
            self.validator = $("#category-form").validate({
                rules: {
                    // JQuery Validation Rules
                }
            });
        };
        return CategoryModel;
    });
```

**NOTES**

- Each of the `init()` functions works fine, since they initialize **kendo grids** and I can see them working fine.
- When I try call `create()` on any of them, they throw errors about the fields being null. Example: `self.validator is undefined` (I call reset on the **validator** inside `create()`).
- So what I did was run the following inside of FireBug:
  `alert(JSON.stringify(viewModel.postModel));`
  This just shows  `{}`, so we can see an empty object here.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- I tried changing everything to singleton, for example:

`var CategoryModel = {}`

instead of:

`var CategoryModel = function () {};`

That seemed to prevent the `viewModel.postModel` and others from being null, BUT it caused other problems. Mostly scoping problems with the `this` keyword and I couldn't set `var self = this;` anywhere successfully - even when I did it in `activate()`, it would still not work - I would get the main view model or something else when accessing `this`. So I think the way I have it setup now is the safest regarding scoping, but for some reason those 3 fields are always NULL.

I have been tearing my hair out for days on this one. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

When I run the following in the console:

`alert(JSON.stringify(viewModel))`

I get:

`{"postModel":{},"categoryModel":{},"tagModel":{},"__moduleId__":"viewmodels/admin/blog"}`

As you can see, the 3 child models are empty objects and for some reason, the following functions are missing as well:

```
self.showCategories = function () { }
self.showPosts = function () { }
self.showTags = function () { }
```

I have completely run out of ideas on this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, for some reason `self.validator` was always NULL. My ***guess*** is the module is being evaluated before the HTML is injected into the Durandal placeholder. Therefore, when `self.validator = $("#post-form").validate({` is being evaluated, the form with ID `#post-form` does not exist on the page and therefore `self.validator` is undefined.

So my solution was to only assign `self.validator` in my `init()` function which is called during the `attached` callback in the **Durandal** lifecycle.